# Maven plugin classloading

Tags: maven-2, classloader

Could anybody please explain how the [Core Classloader](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html) loads resources when, for instance, surefire test plugin is used?

What I'd especially need to know is the order in which project sources and resources from target/classes + target/test-classes AND project dependencies are loaded.

For instance, if I have a resource which exists both in a project and in a dependency. Which one is loaded first?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the answer was really simple.

First off, one can see the plugin classpath in the debug mode, $mvn test -X

And the first entry is `target/test-classes`, then `target/classes` and then plugins and all the project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: For example, jetty-plugin uses its own dependencies&classloader to configure Jetty. For example, in my case I wanted to override HashSessionMAnager (because of http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Session-optimization-td3321009.html). Running mvn jetty:run kept pushing in the standard HashSessionMAnager.

To override jetty-plugin's dependencies I had to make a jar out of my little overridden HashSessionMAnager and place a dependency block

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
          ...
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

inside jetty-plugin block. I guess it makes sense normally, when nothing is injected from the plugin to the real application, but might give you funky surprises.